# How do I align div like this?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to put 4 divs: 2 per line, side by side. Like the below image. Here's what I tried so far:

```
<div style="width: 800px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">aaaa</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">bbbb</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">cccc</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">dddd</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

This does align them side by side, but on the same line.

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="width: 800px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">aaaa</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">bbbb</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">cccc</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">dddd</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine. How can I add some space berween the divs on vertical? `margin` is enlarging the entire div I don't want to that but only add the spaces.

Comment: >How can I add some space berween the divs on vertical? You can set margin in the br tag: <br style="clear: left; margin-top: 50px" />

Answer (score 2):

This should do it - but be wary of earlier versions of IE that don't support inline-block.

**For IE < 8 - Yes, people still use them!**

(use the below example in an external CSS file rather than inline CSS)

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .left, .right {
          display:inline;
          zoom:1;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**For Chrome, FF etc and later IE versions**

This should be OK - but bear it won't scale nicely on mobile devices.
http://jsfiddle.net/re664kmd/

```
<style type='text/css'>
    div.container {
      width:800px;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    div.left, div.right {
      display:inline-block;
      width:200px;
      height:100px;
    }
    div.left {
      background:#00aeed;
    }
    div.right {
      background:#bed700;
    }
</style>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
  <br />
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

To make your life even easier - consider having a play with Bootstrap :D
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I feel like we should start adding notes for people using old IE versions. Something like "Please note it's 2015."

Comment: @KaloyanIvanov - Agreed :)

Answer (score 2):

is a responsive grid actually...

```css
.content{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}

.content div{
  padding:20px;
  float:left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:45%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:2.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>d</div>
<div>
```

//just as comment I think the code edition for code snippet has a bug, since is inserting automatically an addition `<div></div>` after `<div>d</div>` weird, but just ignore that the code should work in any browser as you ask for....

Answer (score 1):

I you put enough padding between each other it will force it to go to the next line. Also you should add `float: right`.

Comment: `float:right` isn't necessary if the padding on the same-line divs forces each other to the sides.